# SQL circular foreign key

Tags: sql, foreign-keys

Assume a database holds some accounts and its transactions.

There would be a table `Account` (for simplicity it holds only an id) and a table `Transaction` that has columns `id`, `account_id` (foreign key), `type`, and `value`.

Now, if some money gets deposited there is no problem. `account_id` is chosen and `type` and `value` are defined. But what if I want to transfer money from account a to account b?

I thought about adding some kind of `offset_account_id` to distinguish from where to where but this is not a good solution imo.

Or do I add two transactions for each of the involved accounts? Then I first have to insert both and after update both as they need to have a circular reference to each other.

Third I thought about adding a 'transfer' table that will hold the `transaction_id` of the involved accounts.

My problem with the last solution nonetheless is if I delete account a I want to cascade this throughout the database, all transactions should be deleted automatically. But if I delete a then the transaction for a will disappear and the entry in the transfer table as well but the transaction of account b would still be in the database.

What is a good layout for these 'accounting' problems?

Side question: would you calculate balance at runtime or work with on insert/delete/update triggers to store the balance with the corresponding account?

Comment: Standard Accounting procedure would allow for a table for Accounts Receivable and a table for Accounts Payable. The payable table would be outgoing transactions and the receivable table would be incoming transactions. If one customer paid to another there would be one record in payable table showing the outgoing payment and one record in the receivable table showing the incoming payment.

Comment: Then, any time a record is posted for an ID in the accounts payable table, that would reduce the total account balance for that ID,  and any time a record is posted for an ID in the accounts receivable table, the ID would increase it's account balance .

Comment: Which leaves me with the same problem (I guess). What happens if i delete one account? In case of a transfer the respective incoming or outgoing transaction would be deleted, but where is the reference to the second account in this example? Could you provide a full table layout? Maybe i miss sth here.

Comment: You should keep the accounts independent and create one transaction per account. In a real world case you would probably not be allowed to delete the accounts and transactions.

Comment: I agree with @JoakimDanielson that deleting accounts should not be the way to go, if one account is closed and a new one is opened, then you would just create a record in the accounts payable table showing a complete reduction of the balance and in the accounts receivable table you would show that same payment amount as a record for the new account number. The historical transactions would remain under the old account number, but the new transactions would be posted with the new account number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am posting an example of the tables described above. In this example, the account ID "100" has made a payment of $30 to the account ID of "123". The transaction shows up as a record in the payable table and as a record in the receivable table.

[image: Table Examples]

Then if the account for 100 is closed one day, you would remove the remaining balance from the account by creating a new record in the accounts payable table. If the money is transferred to a new account then a record would also be created in the accounts receivable table. This will show the history of funds moving. If you are wanting to keep track of which accounts are open or closed I would also suggest creating a table that contains all account numbers, customer names, and a column for "open/closed". That way closed accounts will be reflected in your data  and you can still query based on open or closed accounts, but the history will not be deleted, which is vital for good accounting records.

Comment: Thanks for details